# Why is the __dict__ attribute of this function an empty dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, scope, namespaces

I was testing out the pre-defined **dict** attribute on a function, and I got a result I didn't expect to get. Consider the following code:

```
>>> def func():
       x = 7
       a = 0
       print(func.__dict__)

    
>>> func()
{}
```

After all, I did define two variables in the namespace of the function. So why aren't these names appearing in the **dict** attribute of the function?

Comment: Why *should* the local variables of *each* function invocation be in the dictionary of the *single* function object? What would you expect ``func.__dict__`` to contain if the function were called twice, e.g. via nesting or concurrency?

Comment: Because `func` is an object with a `__call__` method. You can check this by calling `dir(func)`. It doesn't know anything about its body until it's called.

Comment: The local namespace during the execution of a function **is not the function instance namespace**. Or else, you could do `func.a`, but you can't. And that wouldn't make sense, anyway, since `a` *does not exist when the function isn't being executed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__dict__` attribute of a function object stores attributes assigned *to the function object*.

```py
>>> def foo():
...     a = 2
...     return a
...
>>> foo.bar = 12
>>> foo.__dict__
{'bar': 12}
```

Attributes of the function *object* are not related to the local variables that exist during the function *call*. The former is unique (there is one `__dict__` per function object) the latter are not (a function may be called multiple times with separate local variables).

```py
>>> def nfoo(n: int):
...     print(f'level {n} before:', locals())
...     if n > 0:
...        nfoo(n - 1)
...     print(f'level {n} after: ', locals())
...
>>> nfoo(2)
level 2 before: {'n': 2}
level 1 before: {'n': 1}
level 0 before: {'n': 0}
level 0 after:  {'n': 0}
level 1 after:  {'n': 1}
level 2 after:  {'n': 2}
```

Note how the `locals` of each level exist at the same time but hold separate values for the same name.

Comment: But if I define a class variable within a class, then that variable will appear in the __dict__ attribute of that class. How is that any different from declaring a variable like `x=7` within a function?

Comment: A function is not a class. The entire point of having both is that these *are* different. Though consider that a function call can be seen similar (not equivalent!) to a class instantiation. The variables (locals) of the function call are separate from the function object, just like the variables (attributes) of the class instantiation are separate from the class object.

Answer (score 2):

A function's `__dict__` holds *attributes*, not local variables. Local variables are specific to each execution of a function, not to the function itself, so you can't get local variable values by inspecting a function.

If you assigned an attribute:

```
func.blah = 3
```

that would show up in the `__dict__`.

(A `__dict__` doesn't hold all attributes - there are other ways to create attributes, which is why `__dict__` itself doesn't show up in the `__dict__`, for example.)

Comment: But if I define a class variable within a class, then that variable will appear in the __dict__ attribute of that class. How is that any different from declaring a variable like `x=7` within a function?

Comment: @spiritedExit0: As MisterMiyagi said, functions and classes are different things with different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`__dict__` is there to support function attributes, it's not a namespace nor a symbol table *for the function body scope*. You can read [PEP-232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) for further information regarding function attributes.